# Problem with multiple face tracking on Spark AR

Tags: augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I try to do multiple face tracking for 3 people and the problem is the first face is perfect but the second and third are wired. Who knows to fix these things please help T_T

ps. I try to separate all materials assets and textures

ps2. I try to hide the visibility 'faceDistortion' of faceTracker1 and 2 and it's work, but the retouching wasn't worked. I want these three work perfectly.

(sorry that i can't attach images here but you can access it via this link
instead https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1P3743AsFbW77woeHPCtsIAffsHKm79dg?usp=sharing)